# How to solve $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin(x_i - \mu) = 0$ for $\mu$? (Maximum likelihood estimation)

Tags: trigonometry, summation, maximum-likelihood, summation-method

The distribution is defined as:

$f(x; k, \mu) = exp(k\cos(x-\mu))$ (I have removed the term before it because it will be $0$ when we take the derivative of the log). We must find the MLE of $\mu$

---

***My work so far***:

- $\prod\limits_{i=1}^n exp(k\cos(x_i - \mu)) = exp(k\cos(x_1 - \mu)k\cos(x_2 - \mu)...k\cos(x_n - \mu)) = \exp(k\sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos(x_i - \mu))$
- taking log: $=k\sum_{i=1}^{n} \cos(x_i - \mu)$
- taking derivative wrt $\mu$: $=k\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin(x_i - \mu)$
- setting to $0$: --> $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sin(x_i - \mu) = 0$

---

I have no idea how to proceed from here. Is there anything I am missing or any calculation errors?

Comment: You could always try to maximize that function using numerical methods in R...not sure how to get $\mu$ as subject of the formula though...or if that is even possible

Comment: But in R, would you not have to input specific values? I am looking for a general representation of $\mu$

Comment: I didnt see something wrong in your calculations. One point is that you do not have to be able to find the MLE in closed form. It seems this is the case for this problem. Here you can solve the problem numerically. Assume you have $n$ dimensional sample $x_1,...,x_n$, then you put them in $\sum_i cos (x_i-\mu)$ over all possible $\mu$ and calculate the value of this sum. Then choose the value of $\mu$ which minimizes $\sum_i cos (x_i-\mu)$ for the given sample $x_1,...,x_n$

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I don't understand though. To minimize summation $cos(x_i - \mu)$, all the terms would have to be $-1$. But solving for that does not give us a specific value of $\mu$. How should I proceed?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören also i must add, we are not given the values of the $x_i$s

Comment: as I told you, not every equation solved will lead to closed forms. So you do not have any closed form. You will abandon trying to fnd a closed form solution. The solution is this: For any given $x_1,...,x_n$, find $\mu=\arg\min_{\mu\in A}\sum_i\cos(x_i-\mu)$, where $A$ is a set. So think like this: assume you have this $\mu=(1/n)\sum_i X_i$ as the maximum likelihood estimator. To find any sample of this estimator, you will need $n$ samples of $x_n$. The story above is the same, without having data samples you wont get any estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess using the last point of your question, you can use the definition of $\sin(A - B) = \sin(A) \cos (B) - \cos(A) \sin(B)$. Thus, 
$$ \sum_i \sin(x_i - \mu) = \sum_i [\sin(x_i) \cos(\mu) - \cos(x_i)\sin(\mu)] = 0$$
now, after some trivial algebra you should get (if and only if $\mu \neq 0$ and $\sum_i \cos(x_i) \neq 0$)
$$\hat{\mu} = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sin (x_i)}{\sum_{i=1}^n \cos (x_i)} \right)$$ which you can now easily compute for any $x_i$'s.